# Why when app is active, creates two alarms...?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, repeat

I have created a event app that accepts alarms both individual and repeating. There is a glitch where if the app is active when the alarm goes off, not one, but two alarms will alert (indicative by the "overlapping" of alarm music offset by approx. 1 second)

However, if the app is killed, ie. onDestroy() only, there will be one and only one alarm

Is anyone familiar with this problem?

(I would post code but it appears a logical flaw with the alarm system...)

The scheduling of alarms:

```
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    // Testing adding the alarm date to this
    Calendar alarmSchedule = Calendar.getInstance();

    // Setting the time:
    alarmSchedule.set(Calendar.HOUR, getAlarmTime().get(Calendar.HOUR));
    alarmSchedule.set(Calendar.MINUTE, getAlarmTime().get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    alarmSchedule.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    alarmSchedule.set(Calendar.YEAR, alarmDate.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    alarmSchedule.set(Calendar.MONTH, alarmDate.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    alarmSchedule.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, alarmDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmSchedule.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the problem two month ago, same as

> two alarms will alert (indicative by the "overlapping" of alarm music offset by approx. 1 second)

alarm start time cause the problem

```
am.set(type, triggerAtMillis, operation);
am.setRepeating(type, triggerAtMillis, intervalMillis, operation)
```

if the type is RTC or RTC_WAKEUP the triggerAtMillis should be System.currentTimeMillis() + delay
if  the type is ELAPSED_REALTIME or ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP the triggerAtMillis should be SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + delay

Comment: Can we we enter a chat, I do not understand why you are choosing the system time, not the actual time of the alarm...?

Comment: My app, only seems to create two alarms, when the app is open/active

Comment: @Sauron I'm sorry, but where is your repeat alarm ? and did your check the time of alarmSchedule? and when you call the set alarm method?

Comment: I found the problem, the source code I'm using sent a broadcast to itself within the broadcast receiver, pretty dumb design,  I didn't catch it